# DDD, Move to trash, how to design it

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have a simple use case where the user can `discard` a `profile`. It is really easy to understand but raise some modeling questions.

1/ Is it okay to have a flag in my `profile` entity to indicate that he is in the trash ?

I don't think. So I would like to have two `ProfileRepository` and `TrashRepository`.

2/ So given those two repositories, in my application service I just have to remove the profile from his repository and add it to the trash. Seems natural but can cause troubles if I cannot have a transaction. (but it is not the case in my app).

However, I'm using a relational database and a first idea would be to use a column to indicate if the row is in the trash or not and having the two repositories working on the same table. I'm not sure that it is a good idea.

I can also add a `discard` method to the `ProfileRepository` so that I don't need the two.

Which is the best solution ? 
Can I set a flag to determinate the status (discarded) in my entity or is it better to have two different entities with different repositories ?

Comment: Why do you object the `discard` flag in `Profile`?

Comment: Because I was thinking that it was not part of the "real life", but after some discussions and reflexion, I think that I was wrong. In fact 'discarded' is more acceptable than 'deleted' or 'active'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discard really is a business command and a command will always mutate the state of the domain. I believe that it's perfectly valid to have a status indicating that the profile has been discarded. What would be wrong is to introduce a property such as [`deleted` or `active`](http://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/) when what you really mean is `discarded`.

However, some thinks that it's sometime useful to model states explicitely: have an entirely different class to represent a discarded profile.

Here's a few links related to explicit state modeling:

http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/03/09/state-pattern-misuse/
http://p2p.wrox.com/book-patterns-principles-practices-domain-driven-design/94718-ch16-explicit-state-modeling-identity-map.html
https://medium.com/@martinezdelariva/explicit-state-modeling-f6e534c33508

Comment: Having an entirely different class is being part of my favorites solutions. But then, may I have to create `ProfileRespository` who deal with `Profile`s and `TrashRepository` who deal with `DiscaredProfile`s or just one with two more oeprations `discard` and `recover` ?

Comment: @Anonymous You would have two different repositories IMO. If you by-pass your domain model for queries (like you should in my opinion) listing profiles of any status together shouldn't be harder. However if you don't then you'll need to interact with many repositories which is not as interesting. One thing I'm not sure is if you could easily store all the states in the same DB table. I haven't checked yet how an ORM like Hibernate would handle this.